# PostgreSQL error: could not extend file no space left on device

Tags: postgresql, storage, database-administration

I'm running a query that duplicates a very large table (92 million rows) on PostgreSQL. After a 3 iterations I got this error message:

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

The query was:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name
AS SELECT * FROM big_table
```

The issue isn't due to lack of space in the database cluster: at 0.3% of max possible storage at the time of running the query, table size is about 0.01% of max storage including all replicas. I also checked temporary files and it's not that.

Comment: I've only seen this in relation to running out of disk space.  You are positive that you are looking at the correct partition?

Comment: Is your database allowed to expand over a certain size? Possibly it has reached this size? 
Same for the temp_db.

Comment: Welcome to SO, very well asked Q. Can you please add error as text instead as link to screenshot. That saves time (a lot of people scan Qs very fast). Tnx.

Answer (score 1):

You are definitely running out of file system resources.

Make sure you got the size right:

```
SELECT pg_table_size('big_table');
```

Don't forget that the files backing the new table are deleted after the error, so it is no surprise that you have lots of free space after the statement has failed.

One possibility is that you are not running out of disk space, but of free i-nodes. How to examine the free resources differs from file system to file system; for ext4 on Linux it would be

```sh
sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/... | grep Free
```

Answer (score 0):

**In case you are running into this issue on Ubuntu**

Open postgresql logs

```
less /var/log/postgresql/...
```

and check in detail what happened when the query failed.

You should find something like

```
ERROR: Writing to file "base/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp26940.121" failed: No space left on device
```

If this is the case, it could be an issue with the lack of free space in your postgres temporary data directory.

To solve it, just then follow [these steps](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/329205/196798).